# What type of laptop connector is this?

Tags: laptop

Does anyone know what type of connector is this? This connector it`s on a old toshiba laptop, which have just HDD, DVD-ROM and 2 USB connectors.

[image]

Comment: How old is old? I haven't seen SCSI on laptops for two decades, but with 50 pins, it's most likley SCSI.

Comment: While it may be SCSI, if the laptop has DVD-ROM it probably isn't THAT old. It may have been for a docking station originally supplied with the laptop, therefore custom pinout. I'd buzz it out with a pin and an ohmmeter to see if the same pins are grounded as in the SCSI spec ... if all the ground pins match it's almost certainly SCSI.

Comment: What model is the laptop? Does the connector come out through the case or is it internal? If so, which side of the case?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an old SCSI 50 pins female connector previously used for HDD.

Follow that [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_connector) for more information.

You can find some adapters on ebay if you want.

Comment: SCSI connectors, standardized since 1989, are polarized (and D-shaped); this isn't.  It probably serves a purpose for some mating object (a dock? an external disk?  A spiffy video card?) that you would need a user manual to identify.